# How to mount USB Drive in Single User Mode in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions, single-user

I have faced a problem where my Mac is not booting up and throwing messages like this continuously.

```
process[182] crashed: opendirectoryd. Too many corpses being created.
```

I tried repairing the Hard Disk and re-installing OS, but that didn't fixed the issue. So before i erase the disk and re-install again, i have to backup my files. So i boot-ed up in Single user mode, but i wasn't able to mount the pen drive, as High Sierra prevents loading unsigned kernel extensions, in this instance msdos kext for mounting my FAT formatted pen drive.

So i eventually fixed it with the help of online forums and i m putting it together so that it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. In order to run un-signed Kernel extensions in Mac, you need to
   disable Apple Signature check for loading Kernel extensions.

   Reboot Mac in Recovery mode(Command + R), then select the menu item "Utilities / Terminal", then run the command

   ```
   csrutil disable
   ```

   Reboot in Single User mode (Command + S)
2. Enter the following commands,

   ```
   fsck –fy

   mount –uw /
   ```
3. Create a directory to mount USB Drive

   ```
   mkdir /Volumes/usbmnt
   ```
4. Before plugging in the USB Drive, get the list of "disk" devices available by running the command

   ```
   ls -l /dev/disk*
   ```
5. Plug in the USB disk
6. Identify the new device entry for the USB disk by again running the command

   ```
   ls -l /dev/disk*
   ```

   Usually the disk will be mounted like '/dev/disk2s1'
7. Identify the file system of the USB disk

   ```
   fstyp /dev/disk2s1
   ```
8. Based on the file system format, mount the USB Drive; my USB format was "FAT", so I used msdos:

   ```
   mount_msdos /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/usbmnt
   ```

That's it; now the USB drive is mounted.  Use the contents of the drive at the path filesystem "/Volumes/usbmnt".

Comment: I just thought I'd note that this is a useful set of commands for just mounting a device in single-user mode... though the question I had was just that, without any need to fix any failures or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to accomplish this is to boot to recovery instead of single user mode. Once in recovery, the system mounts USB drives to /Volumes just like in the full OS except you don't even need your full OS to be bootable.

1. Hold **Command R** when starting
2. Select **Terminal** from the Utilities Menu
3. **Plug** in the USB drive and you are done

Comment: What if I can’t boot to Recovery mode? Is there a way in single user mode to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Recovery mode offers only very broad/limited recovery options and doesn't offer any ability to list directories or copy individual files. If these user-friendly options fail (e.g., a disk check fails or you can't create disk image) then it's not helpful.

Comment: Recovery mode has the terminal app in the utilities folder @S.Imp it’s quite powerful what you can do there if the graphical disk utility fails you for any reason. Did you underestimate the power of step 2 in my answer?

Comment: @bmike I booted my MBP in recovery mode and there was no terminal option anywhere on any menu.

Comment: If you ask a new question, listing the exact version of macOS and Intel / Apple Silicon perhaps we can help you further.