# Fix problem with external hard drive crashing mac

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive

I have an old LACIE hard drive I'd like to pull some files off.  It's a 500G drive formatted with HFS+.
When I plug it into a USB port on my MacBook Pro, running Mac OS 10.15.7, it seems to work fine at first. It takes a little while, but the disk shows up in the Finder and appears to be OK.
But then the Mac crashes - hard. Screen just goes black and I have to hold the power button down for a while to get it to boot again.

Questions:

- Where do I look for log files that might give me a hint as
  to why the Mac is crashing?  Tried the Console app but didn't see anything obvious.
- Any suggestions as to how to proceed? I'd like to recover the files off the device, or failing that I'd like to simply reformat the device so that I can use that 500G of storage.

Comment: Could you see if you can [mount the drive in Recovery or Single User mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/313703/24324)? If that works, that would allow you get the files of the drive onto another one and then format it.

Comment: I had that with a Lacie drive. When I got a new Mac running 12.1 the drive would attach but out of 3 volumes on it 2 would not mount. So in this case hardware failure - I suspect yours is similar. RThis means don't try and reuse it. To get data try removing the hard disc and put it in a new enclosure